# Steps after calculating VIF to deal with multi collinearity

Tags: regression, correlation, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

How do we eliminate variables after calculating VIF ? I have read about step wise removal of variables with high VIF till we reach VIF values below 5.

On the other hand , my professor told me that it is good idea to look at ratio of standard errors and Beta coefficients after calculating VIF to remove variables. Can any one explain how should I go forward with this ratio ?

Comment: There is no agreement on the procedure. You could remove the hard-to-get variables and keep the easier-to-get ones for practical purposes.

Comment: The ratio is generally meaningless.  (That might explain why I have never seen an account of a regression analysis that employed it.)  For procedures that have real meaning and theoretical support, see Chapter 3 of Belsley, Kuh, and Welsch, *Regression Diagnostics.*